# Why is time() not updating my custom time correctly?

Tags: c++

I created a DateTime class. It gives the correct date if it's today's date, and it updates just fine. However, when I make a custom date/time, it's not updating my date correctly. I condensed this large DateTime class with a simple project that I hope you can compile just fine. To compile it, use an empty C++ console project.

I've been working on this for a few days. Originally, the class had its own tm structure, and I got rid of that. Now the class only stores the raw time.

DateTime.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>  

class DateTime
{
private:
    time_t m_rawTime;
    bool m_customDateTime;
public: 
    DateTime();

    static DateTime now();
    void update();   
    std::string toLongDateString(); 
    std::string toLongTimeString();  
    void addDate(const time_t rawTimeDifference);  
    void setDate(const int month, const int day, const int year,
        const int hours24 = 0, const int minutes = 0, const int seconds = 0); 
};
```

DateTime.cpp

```
#include "DateTime.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>  

DateTime::DateTime()
{
    time(&m_rawTime);
    m_customDateTime = false;
}

DateTime DateTime::now()
{
    DateTime dt;

    time(&dt.m_rawTime);
    dt.m_customDateTime = false;

    return dt;
}

void DateTime::update()
{
    if (!m_customDateTime)
    {
        time(&m_rawTime);
    }
    else
    { 
        time_t diff = difftime(m_rawTime, now().m_rawTime);

        addDate(diff);
    }
}  

std::string DateTime::toLongDateString()
{
    char buffer[30];
    tm *timeInfo = localtime(&m_rawTime);

    strftime(buffer, 30, "%m/%d/%Y", timeInfo);

    return std::string(buffer, strlen(buffer));
}

std::string DateTime::toLongTimeString()
{
    char buffer[30];
    tm *timeInfo = localtime(&m_rawTime);

    strftime(buffer, 30, "%r", timeInfo);

    return std::string(buffer, strlen(buffer));
}  

void DateTime::addDate(const time_t rawTimeDifference)
{ 
    m_rawTime += rawTimeDifference; 
} 

void DateTime::setDate(const int month, const int day, const int year,
    const int hours24, const int minutes, const int seconds)
{
    tm *timeInfo = localtime(&m_rawTime);

    timeInfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
    timeInfo->tm_mday = day;
    timeInfo->tm_year = (year - 1900);
    timeInfo->tm_hour = hours24;
    timeInfo->tm_min = minutes;
    timeInfo->tm_sec = seconds;

    m_rawTime = mktime(timeInfo);

    m_customDateTime = true;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "DateTime.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{ 
    DateTime dt;

    // Set a future custom date
    dt.setDate(6, 1, 2019, 5, 0, 0);

    // Show the custom time: 06/01/2019 05:00:00 AM
    std::cout << dt.toLongDateString() << " " << dt.toLongTimeString() << std::endl;

    // Wait for five seconds
    std::cout << "Press a key to continue . . . ";
    getch();
    std::cout << std::endl;  

    // Update the custom time (add difference to the custom time so it's 5 seconds later)
    dt.update(); 

    // I'm getting 07/09/2019 12:58:50 PM
    std::cout << dt.toLongDateString() << " " << dt.toLongTimeString() << std::endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

With a custom date of 06/01/2019 05:00:00 AM, and pausing for 5 seconds, I expect the output to be 06/01/2019 05:00:05 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that your `DateTime::update` function takes the difference between the set date (06/01/2019 05:00:00 AM) and `now` and then *adds that difference* back into the date again, advancing it quite far into the future (more than a month difference between June 1 and April 21.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the problem. I tried altering the difference formula, but I'm not having any luck. Can you please provide a formula or solution using the code above?

Comment: Forgot to tag you.

Comment: I found a solution, but please tell me if there's a better solution. I ended up using Windows.h GetTickCount(). This function is called when the DateTime class is first created. Then in update(), I used DWORD diff = (GetTickCount() - m_initialTickCounts) / 1000; Then I added those seconds to addDate(diff).